# windows openssh server authentification fails with correct password

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sshd

I have 2 computers, one is windows 10, the other is macos 10.15.7. I try to login my windows 10 from my mac with `ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@198.168.3.84`. Again and again, it said `Permission denied, please try again.`. Then I try `ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost` on my windows, it fails again. I'm quite sure that the password is correct, it's the login password of account `quebec`, which is the administor. `laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@198.168.3.84` is windows' output of `whoami`.

There is no problem with windows' openssh client. I can login my mac from windows.

I close windows' firewall.

This is the debug message of `sshd.exe -ddd`:

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 272
debug2: parse_server_config: config __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config len 272
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:30 setting PermitRootLogin yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:31 setting StrictModes no
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:52 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:77 setting Subsystem sftp      sftp-server.exe
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match Group administrators'
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:khudF/t3vmcq7aPwsOUqCe6NSkwpngfqXpy/IOxE4vw
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:IIhCEjqhUPaZIgneTaTnwU6pWHftw1Ri/6HzK3Ihj9M
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:vX2iHtUoj7LB7Z9pXlGIvxEHRcw/ACEJHK0FXc5Yg9g
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 272
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Connection from ::1 port 1677 on ::1 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: spawning "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" -ddd -y
debug2: Network child is on pid 11424
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 4 config len 272
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 00000209CD357210(101)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 272
debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user quebec host ::1 addr ::1 laddr ::1 lport 22
debug3: get_user_token - i am running as quebec, returning process token
debug1: user quebec matched group list administrators at line 85
debug3: match found
debug3: reprocess config:86 setting AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 15.623ms, delaying 11.248ms (requested 6.718ms) [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec querying public key rsa-sha2-512 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 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:RfKJV/XfmfN98xcjUf7ojEg/h9eMx3Hx1vlySzwnyrE [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 00000209CD361060
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys error:2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys': No such file or directory
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
Failed publickey for laptop-qjn9a0b1\\quebec from ::1 port 1677 ssh2: RSA SHA256:RfKJV/XfmfN98xcjUf7ojEg/h9eMx3Hx1vlySzwnyrE
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 6.718ms (requested 6.718ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 6.718ms (requested 6.718ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user laptop-qjn9a0b1\\\\quebec service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 3 failures 2 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug1: Windows authentication failed for user: quebec domain: . error: 1326
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
Failed password for laptop-qjn9a0b1\\quebec from ::1 port 1677 ssh2
debug3: mm_auth_password: user not authenticated [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 93.757ms, delaying 13.727ms (requested 6.718ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
```

This is debug message of `ssh -vvv laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost`.

```
PS C:\Users\1> ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
laptop-qjn9a0b1\\quebec@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
PS C:\Users\1> ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
PS C:\Users\1> ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
PS C:\Users\1> ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
PS C:\Users\1> ssh -vvv laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'laptop-qjn9a0b1\\quebec'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:IIhCEjqhUPaZIgneTaTnwU6pWHftw1Ri/6HzK3Ihj9M
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/1/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:RfKJV/XfmfN98xcjUf7ojEg/h9eMx3Hx1vlySzwnyrE
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:RfKJV/XfmfN98xcjUf7ojEg/h9eMx3Hx1vlySzwnyrE
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\1/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

This is `$env:programdata/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes no
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

So what might be the cause?

Comment: If you are not using a public key you really should disable it, since, your permissions are wrong on the key if it does exist. I hope you know that after so many failed attempts the account most certainly is locked. So the machine name is `laptop-qjn9a0b1` and the Windows username is `quebec`? Windows doesn't agree: `Windows authentication failed for user`

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure. `laptop-qjn9a0b1\quebec` is the output of `whoami`. I once changed my username. My home directory is `C:\Users\1\`. I've tried `ssh laptop-qjn9a0b1\1`, also failed.

Comment: You don’t know your Windows username? You need to verify the machine name.

Comment: @Ramhound `whoami` gives us the correct username and machine name, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out by chance. According to [this link](https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/articles/216425843-General-What-should-I-enter-in-the-Windows-Credentials-dialog-)

> If you log into your computer using a Windows PIN: Using your PIN in the password field will not work. Instead please make sure your Windows account has a password assigned to it. You can do this on your Windows computer by opening up the  Settings app -> Accounts -> Sign In Options and create a Password for your account.

I set my microsoft account password and reboot(it's necessary), then everything works just fine.